# what is the return type of a radio button value is it integer or string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assume I have a radio button and it returns value as `-1`, `-2`, `3` or
`4` etc. what is the type of value it throws? Is it string or integer?
eg.:

```
<input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="Electrician" value="-1" />
<label class="Button" for="Electrician"> Electrician </label>
<input type="radio" name="case-type" class="ButtonState" id="Plumber" value="-2" />
```

what does is the type of -1 or -2 here, should i use an integer variable to bind those values in my code or should i bind the variables in string variables?

```
<label class="Button" for="Plumber">Plumber</label>
```

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: in your browser console: `typeof document.querySelector('input[name="case-type"]').value` would equal "string"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `value` of an `input` element is always a string ([spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlinputelement) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)).

On modern browsers, specialized input elements (`type="number"`, `type="date"`) have additional properties (`valueAsNumber`, `valueAsDate`), but `value` is always a string.